# How to disable dragging on Fullcalendar when perform eventClick (and open a colorbox)?

Tags: fullcalendar, colorbox

I implemented the eventClick event to open a colorbox

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
 if(calEvent.type=='date') {
    $.colorbox({nofollow:true, href:'/this/that/date-edit/'+calEvent.id+'/'+calEvent.part});
 }
})
```

When I click an the event in the calendar, the colorbox opens but in the background the event is dragged around on the calendar moving the mouse. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you describe the problem better. I'm using colorbox without a problem. How do you mean "event is dragged around on the calendar moving the mouse"? You are moving mouse over colorbox and you get this effect? Or something else?

Comment: In which browser do you have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. I'm using colorbox for similar feature and this is my working code

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            if (calEvent.editable) {
                id = calEvent.id;
                displayInput($(this), calEvent.start, calEvent.title);

            } 
        },



 function displayInput(sender, date, title) {

        sender.colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: "#calendarInput" });
        date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
        $('#txtDate').val(date);
        $('#txtDescription').val(title);
    }
```

#calendarInput is div id that's displayed as popup.
There is no such effect if I got you right. I'm using FullCalendar v1.5.1